# Enable right Click detect in surface

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I'm new to Surface development. I want to have mouse right button down (which I guess is Press-and-Hold Event).

Don't know which event I should handle? I have search for couple of forums but none helped. I came to know that Surface has disabled this event. Is it so? (What I want is Long-Press detection which shows  blue/white circle around finger).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have searched in s:SurfaceWindow class for enabling it. Another thing I have tried is MouseRightButtonDown is not working as well (since i am not using mouse I am working with touch display).  and I am looking to work with timer to detect if mouseup is raise after what time interval but again since the surface is multitouch (50 at a time so it's even difficult as well).